# Reverse order of varidic template arguments while constructing a map key

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I am using a variadic template to construct a key for a map, calculating a number to a base:

```
template<typename T>
uint64_t key(int base, T n)
{
    return uint64_t(n) % base;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
uint64_t key(int base, T n, Args... rest)
{
    return key(base, rest...) * base + (uint64_t(n) % base);
}
```

Calling it with `key(10, 1, 2, 3)` gives me a key with decimal value `321`. I would prefer to get `123` for the key, and I have found a solution that works:

```
template<typename T>
uint64_t keyHelper(int& mul, int base, T n)
{
    mul = base;
    return uint64_t(n) % base;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
uint64_t keyHelper(int& mul, int base, T n, Args... rest)
{
    int mul_tmp;
    uint64_t result = keyHelper(mul_tmp, base, rest...) +
        (uint64_t(n) % base) * mul_tmp;
    mul = mul_tmp * base;
    return result;
}

template<typename... Args>
uint64_t key(int base, Args... args)
{
    int mul;
    return keyHelper(mul, base, args...);
}
```

This solution feels like a hack, tho, since it passes around a reference to fix the exponent of multiplications. Is there a simple varidic way where the template calculates the number in the required order, i.e. `123`? I have seen solutions for reversing variadic arguments, and they seem overly complicated.

Comment: There is no simple way to reverse order of arguments in standard C++. You may find some helpers in libraries, maybe Boost::Hana has some. In your case I'd suggest rewriting `a * p^2 + b * p + c` as `(a * p + b) * p + c` so you don't need to reverse order of arguments.

Comment: Maybe there is some simple way of misusing `std::tuple` or another container, but a solution escapes me :/

Comment: it will be as hacky as yours just with a tuple ;)

Comment: @hochl You can `make_tuple` or `forward_as_tuple` and then `std::apply`, but you still have to reverse `std::tuple`, there is no simple way to do that.

Comment: You can try using `sizeof...(Args)` to pre-calculate the base for a given iteration.

Comment: @first comment: I have coefficients `a, b, c, ...` and I can split at `a` and `b, c, ...`. Your solution needs to split `a, c, c, ...` and the last element, which I cannot see an easy way to do.

Comment: Please don't add solutions to the question. Feel free to post an answer if you've found a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++17 I would use fold expression `(op,...)` to do that:

```
template<class B, class ... Args>
auto key(B base, Args ... args) {
    std::common_type_t<Args...> res{};
    ( (res *= base, res += args % base), ... );
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W3qKbvW43)

Comment: I switched to using this solution, so I'll accept that one.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution that feels a little better, following a comment from @Andrey Semashev:

```
template<int n>
uint64_t exp(int base)
{
    return base * exp<n - 1>(base);
}

template<>
uint64_t exp<0>(int base)
{
    return 1;
}

template<typename T>
uint64_t key(int base, T n)
{
    return uint64_t(n) % base;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
uint64_t key(int base, T n, Args... rest)
{
    return key(base, rest...) +
        (uint64_t(n) % base) * exp< sizeof...(rest) >(base);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3K4cbn1xv):

```
template<typename T>
uint64_t key_impl(int base, unsigned int exp, T n)
{
    return uint64_t(n) % base;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
uint64_t key_impl(int base, unsigned int exp, T n, Args... rest)
{
    uint64_t res = uint64_t(n) % base;
    for (unsigned int i = 0u; i < exp; ++i)
        res *= base;
    return key_impl(base, exp - 1u, rest...) + res;
}

template<typename... Args>
uint64_t key(int base, Args... args)
{
    return key_impl(base, sizeof...(Args) - 1u, args...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the number of arguments is known, the maximum exponent is known, and you  can just use that to calculate the sum

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
uint64_t key(int base, T n, Args... rest)
{
    return (uint64_t(n) % base) * std::pow(base, sizeof...(rest))
            + key(base, rest...);
}
```

(the base case is unchanged)

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8hGsq3qn8)

Note that you shouldn't actually use `std::pow` here; write a function that does integer exponentiation instead.